# In the GRAD_DEBT_MDN variable who is in the cohorts used to calculate?

Tags: collegescorecard

I am trying to recreate how this is calculated so I can track our students in real time.  I want to know who is counted in the cohort calculation. I understand it is two years of rolling information based on Fiscal Year cohorts of those that completed. But is it all graduates or only those graduates who had any debt? Also, is the FY July 1 to June 30?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed up with our data team. Here's the response to your question:

> GRAD_DEBT_MDN is student borrowers of federal loans that graduated in
> a given fiscal year. Data are produced for rolling two-year pooled
> cohorts, which for debt are fiscal years Oct 1 – Sep 30.

This was pulled from the [Institution Documentation](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/InstitutionDataDocumentation.pdf) file, around page 18-19 in the Cumulative Median Student Debt section for reference.